# Can shp2sde on ArcSDE 9.3 server operate with SDE 10.3 database?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase

We have 2 servers running ArcSDE 9.3, and one Oracle database at SDE 9.3. Only one of the ArcSDE 9.3 servers is to be upgraded to ArcSDE 10.3, and the Oracle SDE database will be migrated from SDE 9.3 to SDE 10.3. The hope is that the sdp2sde commands on the non-upgraded ArcSDE 9.3 server will be able to operate on the upgraded SDE 10.3 database. I firmly believe that the upgrade to SDE 10.3 will update the database schema such that shp2sde on ArcSDE 9.3 will no longer work. Am I right?

I don’t believe we will be able to download a version of shp2sde for SDE 10.3. It was in was in ArcSDE Administration Command Line Utilities, aka. SDE Commands.

From what I can tell, if we already had 10.2.2 we would perhaps have some SDE commands which would work against SDE 10.3, but not shp2sde.

ESRI expect us to use Python rather than shp2sde.

This is the closest related information that I can find:
[Can ArcSDE command line tools be used against 10.3 and newer geodatabases?](http://www.globalmappertraining.com/component/easyblog/can-arcsde-command-line-tools-be-used-against-10-3-and-newer-geodatabases?Itemid=287)

Confirmation that shp2sde is not in 10.3: [shrug-l: SDE Commands on 64 Bit Servers](http://lists.dep.state.fl.us/pipermail/shrug-l/2011-January/003348.html)
The commands not supported on 64-bit systems are:
cov2sde, sde2cov, sde2shp, shp2sde, shpinfo, sde2tbl, tbl2sde

Comment: Shapefile is an *extremely* unreliable method of transferring data between geodatabases. It mangles column names, trucates date fields, corrupts numeric NULLs,... Instead, use file geodatabase or XML workspace, or just drag and drop using 10.2.

Comment: Hi @Vince, We have legacy systems which generate Shapefiles, and nightly scripts that import them, so it'll be a while before we are done with Shapefiles....

Comment: Then you'll just need to learn how to use Python for this.  It shouldn't take more than half an hour.

Comment: Hi @Vince, I actually have it running both in ArcObjects (with GeoProccessing), and Python, but I need a definitive answer to my question "Am I right?" before I can commit further resources to solving this totally...

Comment: Yes, of course 9.3 binaries can't operate with a 10.3 geodatabase. They weren't supported  with 10.0, much less a release four versions in the future. 9.3 has been retired 18 months, and 10.0 for five. 10.3 is documented as only supporting 9.3 servers for upgrade (not use), though it seems unlikely that the database releases supported by 9.3 would be compatible with 10.3. 10.4 is even more restrictive on the database releases it supports. At this point you're nearly past "upgrade" and approaching "reinstall and migrate".

Comment: For definitive answers call esri tech support. I heard the command line tools are deprecated at 10.3, but some  10.2 commands work on 10.3. I recommend you go with the flow and move to python.